# Cannot update radio input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, json.net

I have two radio buttons

```
<div class="radio">                            
   <input class="i-radio" type="radio" name="rbtnRoundTrip" checked="checked" value="OneWayTrip" />
</div>
<div class="radio">                            
   <input class="i-radio" type="radio" name="rbtnRoundTrip" value="RoundTrip" />
</div>
```

I have a value on my variable

```
Var Tripway;
```

That is "OneWayTrip" or "RoundTrip" so now i am trying to select the coresponding radio button.

```
$('#FormSearch input[type="radio"][name="rbtnRoundTrip"][value="' + Tripway + '"]').trigger('click');
```

But this code never selects the radio button with the values "RoundTrip". Even if the value of the variable is "RoundTrip" the radio button is always checked on OneWayTrip

Answer (score 0):

You should use `prop()` method instead of `trigger('click')` like following.

```js
var Tripway = "RoundTrip";
$('#FormSearch input[type="radio"][name="rbtnRoundTrip"][value="' + Tripway + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="FormSearch">
    <div class="radio">
        <input class="i-radio" type="radio" name="rbtnRoundTrip" checked="checked" value="OneWayTrip" />
    </div>
    <div class="radio">

        <input class="i-radio" type="radio" name="rbtnRoundTrip" value="RoundTrip" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: no its not working. It is  not select the second radio button

Comment: It depends on `Tripway ` value. Change `Tripway ` value to `RoundTrip`. @focus

Comment: On debuger i am taking "Object doesn't support property or method 'prop'"

Comment: I don't know how you tried. Can you show your full code or create a fiddle? @focus

Answer (score 0):

do it like

```
$('#FormSearch input[type="radio"][name="rbtnRoundTrip"][value="' + Tripway + '"]').prop("checked", true).trigger('click');
```

Considering you want to trigger click event too.

If you are using old jquery then user `.attr("checked", "checked")` instead of `.prop("checked", true)`